# Windows lock mode while sendkeys or mouse control c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, mouse, remote-access, sendkeys

So I've got application that uses webbrowser and going through specified website.

At the end of the process it clicks on button and Download dialog box appear. Problem is: to download this file I have to either SendKeys or position properly mouse and simulate clicks.. When I have remote desktop open it works well, but when I disconnect SendKeys give error "Access denied" - I believe it's related to windows lock mode, and mouse is not moving at all..

Is there any possibility that I can make it work? I found that there is no other option to download that file than SendKeys or simulate mouse position and clicks.. I have to stick to webbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to visually click on the button, or link? just in `DocumentCompleted` event of the WebBrwoser invoke the click event:

```
public void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) 
{
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    wb.Document.GetElementById("someElementId").InvokeMember("click");

}
```

Of course in this example I have used `GetElementById()` however you may use any method or loops, ... to find the element you want.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear at first time: after clicking on button file download dialog shows - you can't control this dialog from WebBrowser control. It's IE based.